# Enable @PrePersist and @PreUpdate in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, repository-pattern

How does one turn on the required Spring / JPA / Hibernate behaviours to invoke @PrePersist and @PreUpdate hooks?

Our stack includes those three and a Repository for each entity, but we feel it is better to model this as a resposibility of the entity itself with the help of these hooks, but they are not called. Each Repository has an EntityManager injected. I am using those EntityManagers, not Sessions.

The EntityManager is created by a `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` which uses the `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` and `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`. There is a `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` present. The factory references a `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`.

Is it necessary to manually install / wire the something in (an entity listener?) to ensure the calls are made. I cannot locate any documentation for this.

Comment: Do you use them as [documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)? Note, they don't work if you use the session API. Can you show some code and config?

Comment: There is no code written, except for annotations on methods that are not called. By linking to the documentation for creating my own entity listener, are you saying there isn't one in Spring that can be simply switched on?    I am using EntityManager, not Session.

Comment: I realise my terminalogy may have been wrong. I'm not looking to create application code, but to leverage framework code to ensure existing entity methods with `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate` are called appropriately.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring it's simple JPA 1.0. And no, you won't have to write any additional code if everything is as it's expected by Hibernate. I'm asking for your entity code because those annotations cannot be placed everywhere: method can have any name, no parameters, return type of void, method should not be final or static, no checked exceptions should be thrown, any annotation can be only used on one method.

Comment: Maybe the [JPA WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events) has further hints.

Comment: @Simon What is the problem - is that the annotation `@PrePersist` is not recognized? Or do you wonder if it is indeed called when it should?

Comment: The problem was that the methods were not called.