# How to create a customerNumber generator for each company in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a table of customers, each customer belongs to a company, companies want their customer numbers to start at 0 and increment as they add customers and when companyB adds a customer, companyA's customer numbers shouldn't be affected. CustomerId internally can be any number, customerNumber must be incremented gap-free in the context of the companyId (with gap-free I mean 0,1,2,3,4, if 2 is deleted, it's gone, the next insert should be 5 and not 2)

```
Example: 
    companyId customerNumber  customerId 
    0         0               0
    0         1               1
    0         2               2
    0         3               3
    0         4               4
    0         5               5
    1         0               6
    1         1               7
    1         2               8
```

I was wondering if there's a better way to do it than opening a transaction, finding the max customerNumber, inserting an entry using the max+1 as customerNumber and closing transaction

Is there some sort of annotation I can use where I can specify the criteria for generating a customerNumber? The next customerNumber should be the highest number available within that company. (I have about 20 other entities that have similar human-readable-incremental-id requirements based on date and comapnyId and I want to make the customerNumber-type fields generation as fool-proof as possible, I don't want to have to remember to do it everytime I persist a new entity)

Something like:

```
@SequenceGenerator(uniqueOver="companyId,customerNumber",strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long customerNumber;
```

The solution should be ACID compliant since I'm working with stock and financial data.

**Update**: I've renamed id to customerId and customerId to customerNumber to prevent confusion.

**Update**:
When I mean gap-free, I mean that customerNumbers should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - if I delete number 4 it is gone forever and the next insert should be 10 unless I create a new company, then their first customer should start at 0.

**Update**:
I'm using spring with hibernate, so the @PrePersist annotation is not working for me. If @PrePersist is suggested as a solution, then it needs to work under spring, so an answer for Simon's question would be needed: [Enable @PrePersist and @PreUpdate in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458473/enable-prepersist-and-preupdate-in-spring)

**Suggested Answer which I'm not sure about:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {

    @Table(name = "CustomerNumber")
    @Entity(name = "sequenceIdentifier")
    public static class CustomerNumberSequenceIdentifier {

        @Id
        @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence", strategy = "sequence", parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequenceName", value = "sequence"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "allocationSize", value = "1"),
        })
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Long id;

    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long customerId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequenceIdentifier", strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long customerNumber

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using hibernate;
Example Query

`Query query = session.createQuery("insert into customer (company_id, customer_id)" +"(select :company_id, IFNULL(max(customer_id),1)+1 from customer where company_id = :company_id)");`

```
    //set the company_id here

    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Note: IFNULL is a MYSQL specific syntax

I suggest keeping the company id `auto_increment` field in a separate company master table.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't speak to the hibernate side of things (sorry), you can accomplish this with a table in mysql so long as it uses the myisam engine, with the following table structure:

```
create table ai_test (
    company_id integer,
    customer_number integer auto_increment,
    primary key (company_id, customer_number)
) engine=MyISAM;
```

Here's a fiddle showing that in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45e78/1

Sorry i can't translate this to hibernate for you - never used it, but this may be a starting point.

**edit**
since inno is required, you could use this table and trigger:

```
create table ai_test (
    company_id integer,
    customer_number integer,
    primary key (company_id, customer_number)
) engine=InnoDB;


create trigger inno_composite_ai_ok before insert on ai_test
for each row 
begin
    set new.customer_number =     
        (select ifnull((select max(customer_number)+1 
                         from ai_test 
                           where 
                        company_id=new.company_id),1));
end//
```

Here is a sample fiddle for you:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fffd0/14

**edit**
One more update to include requirement of single column PK

```
create table ai_test (
    company_id integer,
    customer_no integer,
    customer_id integer primary key auto_increment

) engine=InnoDB;

create trigger inno_composite_ai_ok before insert on ai_test
for each row 
begin
    set new.customer_no =     
        (select ifnull((select max(customer_no)+1 
                         from ai_test 
                           where 
                        company_id=new.company_id),1));
end//
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37436/1)

Note you can (and probably should) put a unique constraint across company_d/customer_no

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a sequence number generation without having to write the ddl to generate a new sequence number for each table.  Do this with a separate sequence number table and create a select for update transaction to lock both tables for insert.  Hibernate does this with enhanced-tables.

Here's a pretty good example:
http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/

Scroll down to the TABLE(SEQUENCE) section, which is a table of sequence numbers solution.

In the example just specify the customer name as the sequence name to get the right sequence.

The overhead is generating a sequence row for every new company, and locking the table for every new customer.

Comment: Your TableSequenceIdentifier class, I'm assuming that would be, in my case, the Customer class? How would I get the customer numbers per company using the table sequence example?

Comment: The table sequence identifier class is a separate table that just stores sequence values for your customers. It will hold the companyid and the next sequence value for that company. Hibernate provides enhanced tables to do the select for update/update strategy to wrap your insert transaction.  This gives you a lock safe sequence update. Your customer table insert will now rely on the table sequence identifier class.

Comment: I'm not quite following ... I've updated my question, customerId is an auto-incrementing field, each Company can have multiple customers and each customerNumber should be incrementing per company. Is my CustomerNumberSequenceIdentifier class correct for what I'm trying to do and how do I bring it into the CustomerNumber so that I can get customer numbers that increment per company as per my example above? The examples I'm finding are all just showing how that sequence number table is generating sequences.
Feel free to edit the hibernate model in my question and fill in the gaps.